# Confusion about subtleties in the proof of "negative times positive is negative" and the like?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, ordered-fields

I am answering exercise $1.2.4:$

> [image]

I'm letting the other problems in here just for reference of what was already done so that it's clear what we can use. The answer to $1.2.4$ is:

> [image]

I am a bit confused: For example, in the first case he comes to the conclusion that $(-a)b>0$, in my mind from here we just need to write $(-a)b=-ab>0$ and then add $ab$ in both sides so that we get $0>ab$ but instead of doing that, he chose to write $ab=[-(-a)b]=(-1)(-a)b=-((-a)b)<0$. I get what he is doing in this expression, I just don't get why he did that instead of what I pointed out.

I am trying to understand the following subtleties here:

- Does this happens because we don't know that $a(-b)=-ab$?

I once saw a proof of this fact that was something like:

$$(b+(-b))=0\tag{$\text{Inverse for +}$}$$

$$a(b+(-b))=0 \tag{$a\cdot0=0$}$$

$$ab+a(-b)=0 \tag{$\text{Distributivity}$}$$

$$ a(-b)=-ab\tag{$\text{Subtract ab}$}$$

- I am a bit confused: Is this proof correct? I just noted that in it, we don't mention any ordering axioms at all which seems to be where the ideas of "positive/negative" come from, although, it seems there exists some "similarity" in the meaning of "positive/negative" and additive inverses.

Comment: "exercise 1.2.4" of which book? What is the context? Mainly: what are you supposed to know and what to ignore?

Comment: @AnneBauval We know the axioms for fields, the axioms of ordering and the truth of exercises $1.2.1$ to $1.2.3$.

Comment: Which axioms for fields? And which corollaries are you supposed to ignore? I mean: you are asking us whether you are supposed to ignore that $a(-b)=-ab$ but how could *we* know? (Btw, your proof is correct and idependent from ordering, as well as the proof from your book.)

Comment: @AnneBauval The properties in [this page](https://i.imgur.com/jmw6ywJ.png).

Comment: Ah, the book is Omar Hijab's: "Introduction to Calculus and Classical Analysis".

Comment: As already said, both proofs are correct and have nothing to do with ordering. Your book prefers his own simply because it is deduced from exercise 1.2.3.

Comment: In your argument, when you "add $ab$ to both sides", that is another step you need to justify. It's not hard, of course, but it is something that's not in 1.2.1 to 1.2.3.

Comment: @bof Typo, corrected already.